# ¿ Existe alguna biblioteca en Java para el cálculo simbólico?

Tags: java

Concretamente, necesito trabajar con las **letras del abecedario y las operaciones de suma y producto**, además de mantener el orden de preferencia simbólica, propiedades de distribución, asociación, etc. Por ejemplo:

A+(BC+A)C = A + BCC + AC

Como se puede observar, necesito que el **producto sea la concatenación** y que esta respete el orden de las letras, es decir, AC != CA, por ejemplo. También es necesario que **la expresión quede lo más extendida posible**, es decir, sin paréntesis ni símbolos de por medio que no sean el de la suma.

He intentado escribir mi propio código al respecto, pero es muy problemático e ineficiente. Gracias y espero sus respuestas

Comment: [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/), [SymJava](https://github.com/yuemingl/SymJava) y [javaCalc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javacalculus/) pueden ser lo que buscas.